# dynamic UITableViewCell height programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create a tableview cell programmatically with varying heights.

```
//  Created by AJ Norton on 7/29/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 AJ Norton. All rights reserved.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

  var arr = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "he"

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine

    self.tableView.registerClass(CustCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustCellTableViewCell

    cell.label.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageContainer.image = UIImage(named: arr[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var i = UIImage(named: arr[indexPath.row])!
    return CGFloat(i.size.height + 15.0)
  }
}
```

**this is my Custom cell:**

```
//  Created by AJ Norton on 7/29/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 AJ Norton. All rights reserved.

import UIKit

class CustCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  lazy var imageContainer: UIImageView = {
    var i = UIImageView()
    i.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    return i
  }()

  lazy var label: UILabel = {
    var l = UILabel()
    l.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    l.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return l
  }()

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.addSubview(label)
    self.addSubview(imageContainer)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    var viewDict = ["label": label, "image": imageContainer]

    var constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-5-[image]-5-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewDict)
    var constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[label]-[image]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewDict)
    var constraint3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[label]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewDict)

    self.addConstraints(constraint1)
    self.addConstraints(constraint2)
    self.addConstraints(constraint3)

    self.sizeToFit()
  }
}
```

When I run the app I get this: [image].  I want the images to take up their maximum height (300px) for the cell (Also the whole background should be green.

Answer (score 0):

just delete self.sizeToFit() and it works.